# Add a comma to a position which following some pattern in R

Tags: r

I used asked this question before, but I found the R code I used could not apply to all situation:

for examples:
    row 8: additional comma was added, I don't want this.
    row 6-7: how could I deal with multuple conditions such as x1,x2,x3,x1~2,x1~3 after ")";
    row 3-5: mat, pat or dn are three condition for that position;

Basically I want add a comma after mat or pat or dn, if there is no "mat", "pat" or "dn", add a comma after x1 or x2 or x3 or x1~2 or x1~3; But if there is a comma already, I don't want add another one. I highlight the position I want to comma inside of "," in the results I want.

```
> x <- c(
   'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x311p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3',
   'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x211p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat',
   'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat',
   'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 pat13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat',
   'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 dn13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat',
   'arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~2 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish', 
   'arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~3 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish',
   'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)',
   'nuc ish(D21S259/D21S341/D21S342x3).arr(21)x310q26.12(121812494-122486677)x1'
 )

> sub(pattern = '([(]\\d+-\\d+[)]x[1-3|"1~3"|"1~2"](\\smat)?)', replacement = '\\1,', x=x)
[1] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3"  
[2] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x2,11p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat"                               
[3] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat,13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat"                           
[4] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1, pat13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat"                           
[5] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1, dn13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat"                            
[6] "arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1,~2 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish"           
[7] "arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1,~3 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish"           
[8] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)"
[9] "nuc ish(D21S259/D21S341/D21S342x3).arr(21)x310q26.12(121812494-122486677)x1,"    

**Here are results I want to get:** 
  'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3**,**11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3',
  'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x2**,**11p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat',
  'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat**,**13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat',
  'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 pat**,**13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat',
  'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 dn**,**13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat',
  'arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~2**,** Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish', 
  'arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~3**,** Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish',
  'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3**,**11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)',
  'nuc ish(D21S259/D21S341/D21S342x3).arr(21)x3**,**10q26.12(121812494-122486677)x1'
```

Comment: please format your code properly. currently it's a jumbled mess.

Comment: You should also describe the pattern in words where you want to add a comma.

Comment: Basically I want add a comma after mat or pat or dn, if there is no "mat", "pat" or "dn", add a comma after x1 or x2 or x3 or x1~2 or x1~3;   But if there is a comma already, I don't want add another one.  I highlight the position I want to comma inside of **,** in the results I want.

Comment: In your desired results, the first string, there is a `pat`, so why do you add the comma after `x3` and not after `pat`? In your question you say *"if there is no "mat", "pat" or "dn", add a comma after x1"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches the description in the question, although it does not match the desired result. Hopefully you can edit it to match your needs.

```
add_comma = function(x) {
    no_comma = !grepl(pattern = ",", x = x, )

    # first try to add after mat, pat or dn
    x[no_comma] = sub(pattern = "(\\smat|\\pat|\\sdn)", replacement = "\\1,", x = x[no_comma])
    no_comma = !grepl(pattern = ",", x = x)

    #next try after x1, x2, x3, not followed by tilde
    x[no_comma] = sub(pattern = "(x[1-3])([^~])", replacement = "\\1,", x = x[no_comma])
    no_comma = !grepl(pattern = ",", x = x)

    #last try after x1~2 or x1~3
    x[no_comma] = sub(pattern = "(x1~[2-3])", replacement = "\\1,", x = x[no_comma])

    return(x)
}

add_comma(x)
# [1] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x311p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat,.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3" 
# [2] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x211p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat,"                              
# [3] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat,13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat"                          
# [4] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 pat,13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat"                          
# [5] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 dn,13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat"                           
# [6] "arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~2 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1,ish"           
# [7] "arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~3 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1,ish"           
# [8] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)"
# [9] "nuc ish(D21S259/D21S341/D21S342x3,.arr(21)x310q26.12(121812494-122486677)x1"
```

As you can see, it first tries to add a comma after the first occurrence of `mat`, `pat`, or `dn`. If that fails, it adds a comma after `x1`, `x2`, or `x3` *not* followed by a tilde. If that fails, it adds a comma after `x1~2` or `x1~3`.